# Hide title after CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following problem:
I created a CollapsingToolbarLayout and below the title I added a TabLayout in gray color.

Screen with/after CollapsingToolbarLayout:

[image] [image]

The problem:
When it slides I would like only TabLayout to be fixed.
How can I remove or hide the title when sliding the content?

Code x m l:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="70dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/backexemplo"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarPerfilEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
             />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Code java:

```
public class PerfilEmpresaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                private Toolbar mToolbar = null;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil_empresa);
                    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarPerfilEmpresa);
                    // mToolbar.setLogo( R.drawable.paypal );
                    mToolbar.setTitle("NomeApp");

                    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Tanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Title");
    appBarLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" "); // Careful! There should be a space between double quote. Otherwise it won't work.
                isShow = false;
            } else if (!isShow) {       
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Title");
                isShow = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved the problem:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarPerfilEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
             />
Add:
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
```